# Order of an entire function less than 1 implies exponential type 0

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have following definitions at disposal:

- exponential type $\tau$ of an entire function $f$ is defined as: \begin{align*}
  \tau = \limsup\limits_{r \to \infty}^{} \frac{\log M(r)}{r}
  \end{align*}where $M(r)=\max \{\:\lvert f(z) \rvert : \lvert z \rvert\ = r\}$ is the maximum modulus function.
- (finite) order $\rho$ of an entire function $f$ is defined as the infimum of all numbers $a>0$ which satisfy \begin{align*}
  M(r) \leq \exp(r^a)  
  \end{align*} for $r>R$ , or equivalently as: \begin{align*}
  \rho = \limsup\limits_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log(\log M(r))}{\log r}
  \end{align*}

It is often mentioned in literature that entire functions of order less than $1$ have the exponential type $0$:
\begin{align*}
\rho < 1 \implies \tau = 0 
\end{align*}

> Question: How does one formally prove this?

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\log(\log M(r))}{\log r} < 1 \iff \log_{\,r} \log M(r) < 1 \iff \log M(r) <r \iff \frac{\log M(r) }{r} < 1
\end{align*}
which is the expression from the definition of $\tau$. From here I'm not sure what I should do or if I'm heading in the right direction.
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that
$$
\rho = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log(\log M(r))}{\log r} < 1
$$
and choose a number $a \in (\rho, 1)$. Then, for sufficiently large $r$,
$$
\begin{align}
 &\frac{\log(\log M(r))}{\log r} \le a \\
\implies \quad &\log M(r) \le r^a \\
\implies \quad &\frac{\log M(r)}{r} \le r^{a-1} \, .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
0 \le \tau = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log M(r)}{r} \le \lim_{r \to \infty} r^{a-1} = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!